# Newtons Divided Difference practice problem

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

I haev a midterm tomorrow in Numerical Analysis and I was attempting to work my way through a practice problem. However I get stuck.
I notice we have 2 points and can find a degree 1 polynomial using Newton's divided difference. But how would we use the derivative to extend this to a degree 2 polynomial? Thank you.

[image: Attempting to solv this problem]

Comment: In not an expert of Newton divided difference but you have 3 unknown and 3 condition. The system is solvable. Where is the problem? The first equation leads to $\alpha = f_0$, second $\beta = (f_1 - f_0)/(x_1 - x_0)$ and the third is (following my reasoning) $\gamma = (f'_2 - \beta)/(2x_2 - x_1 - x_0)$

Comment: Ah I see, so the 3rd term, did you get that by taking the derivative of P(x) and then solving for gamma? That was my thought actually immediately after I posted the question and I seem to have gotten the same answer as you.

Comment: Yes you got it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved in comment by [Emar](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/45731/emar):

> In not an expert of Newton divided difference but you have 3 unknown and 3 condition. The system is solvable. Where is the problem? The first equation leads to $\alpha = f_0$, second $\beta = (f_1 - f_0)/(x_1 - x_0)$ and the third is (following my reasoning) $\gamma = (f'_2 - \beta)/(2x_2 - x_1 - x_0)$

Comment: Please add the solution from the comments, otherwise this is "not an answer" and will be deleted.